# How to run data factory pipeline using WebActivity/Rest using optional uri parameter like isRecovery , startFromFailure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory

I can to execute  a pipeline in data factory using Web activity /Rest API.
But I am trying to rerun a pipeline in data factory from the failure activity using Web activity/Rest API.

As per the documentation I have to pass IsRecovery , referencePipelineRunId and startFromFailure uri parameters.

I am doing it , but a new run is generated for the pipeline instead of starting from failure activity. These optional parameters are not recognized correctly.

May be, I am not able to pass the these optional parameter values in correct format.  How to pass boolean uri parameters IsRecovery , startFromFailure ?  Any example uri with these optional parameters would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have your answer, the first time I tried ADF API, specially the post methods I hit the same issue.

The problem here is that, the method you need is a POST, although there's no body content, so you need to specify an empty body.

So I was able to execute your request.

here's a sample URL:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/some-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/your-data-factory/pipelines/your-pipeline-name/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01&referencePipelineRunId=the-failed-runid&isRecovery=true&startFromFailure=true

so for boolean values, is like that, simple.

Now the tricky piece:
[image]

Make sure you choose POSt method.

For Body, enter a dynamic expression, do not type plain text like {}, it will work, once, then if you go there again it will disappear.

On dynamic expression use:

```
@json('{}')
```

This will represent an empty json body and will persist :)

Then of course setup proper authentication method, in my case ADF was granted against itself to make my life easier.